# How to properly redirect, when redirecting, query wont input values into database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, redirect

How do i properly redirect to another page? here are my codes.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="payout.css"/>
<font face='calibri'>
<?php
    session_start();
    $conn = @mysql_connect("localhost","root","mypassword");
    $db = @mysql_select_db("buybranded");
    include("includes/functions.php");
    mysql_set_charset("UTF8");

    if(isset($_GET['command']) && $_GET['command']=='update'){


        $first_name=$_SESSION['first_name'];
        $email=$_SESSION['email'];
        $home_address=$_SESSION['home_address'];
        $mobile_phone=$_SESSION['mobile_phone'];
        $carrier=$_REQUEST['carrier'];
        $payment=$_REQUEST['payment'];

        $result=mysql_query("insert into customers values('','$first_name','$email','$home_address','$mobile_phone','$carrier','$payment')");

        $customerid=mysql_insert_id();
        date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Hong_Kong");
        $date=date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
        $result=mysql_query("insert into orders values('','$date','$customerid')");
        $orderid=mysql_insert_id();

        $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
        for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
            $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
            $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
            $price=get_prod_price($pid);
            mysql_query("insert into order_detail values ($orderid,$pid,$q,$price)");
        }

    }
//  else if(isset($_REQUEST['success']) && $_REQUEST['success']=='1'){
//  header('refresh: 0; url=samplebrand.php');
//  $message = "Thank you for buying, You will now be redirected";
//  echo("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>");
//  }
    ?>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Billing Info</title>
<script language="javascript">

    function validate(){
        var f=document.form1;
        f.command.value='update';
        f.submit();
        alert("Order submitted");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <form name="form1" onsubmit="return validate()">
    <input type="hidden" name="command" />
    <div align="center">
        <h1 align="center">Shipping and Payment</h1>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="2px">
            <tr><td>Order Total:</td><td>₱ <?php echo get_order_total()?></td><td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
        </table>
                    <center><h1>Shipping Method</h1></center>
            <form method="post">
            <table width="900" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" id='center'>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="carrier" <?php if (isset($carrier) && $carrier=="LBC") echo "checked";?>  value="LBC"></td>
                    <td><img src="img/LBC.jpg" alt="LBC" class="picture"/></td>
                    <td><p>The Shipping takes 1-2 days for NCR and 2-3 days for any provincial.<p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="carrier" <?php if (isset($carrier) && $carrier=="COD") echo "checked";?>  value="COD"></td>
                    <td><img src="img/Cash on Delivery.jpg" alt="COE" class="picture" height="90" width="125"/></td>
                    <td><p>This service is only available for Meto Manila and Metro Cebu.<p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="carrier" <?php if (isset($carrier) && $carrier=="Personal") echo "checked";?>  value="Personal"></td>
                    <td><img src="img/buybranded2.jpg" alt="buybranded" class="picture"/></td>
                    <td><p>The Shipping takes 2-3 days after processing for NCR and 3-5 days for any provincial.<p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="carrier" <?php if (isset($carrier) && $carrier=="NextDayDelivery") echo "checked";?>  value="NextDayDelivery"></td>
                    <td><img src="img/NextdayDelivery.jpg" alt="NextDayDelivery" class="picture"/></td>
                    <td><p>The Shipping takes 1-2 days for NCR and 2-3 days for any provincial.<p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="carrier" <?php if (isset($carrier) && $carrier=="SameDayDelivery") echo "checked";?>  value="SameDayDelivery"></td>
                    <td><img src="img/Same day Delivery.jpg" alt="SameDayDelivery" class="picture"/></td>
                    <td><p>Available only for NCR. Get your sporting good/s the same day you purchase the item. Cutoff is 12noon.<p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="carrier" <?php if (isset($carrier) && $carrier=="PickUp") echo "checked";?>  value="PickUp"></td>
                    <td><img src="img/Pick-up.jpg" alt="Pick-Up" class="picture"/></td>
                    <td><p>Office hours: 10:00 am to 6:00 pm<p></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br>
            <br>
        <center><h1>Payment Method</h1></center>
        <table width="900" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" id='centerdown'>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="payment" <?php if (isset($payment) && $payment=="BPI") echo "checked";?>  value="BPI"></td>
                    <td><img src="img/BPI.jpg"></td>
                    <td><p>Pay by BPI bank deposit (we need confirmation of payment through email.)<p></td>
                </tr>
                <!--
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="payment" <?php if (isset($payment) && $payment=="PayPal") echo "checked";?>  value="PayPal"></td>
                    <td><img src="img/paypal.gif"></td>
                    <td><p>Pay with your PayPal account, credit card (CB, Visa, Mastercard...), or private credit card.<p></td>
                </tr>
                -->
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="payment" <?php if (isset($payment) && $payment=="PickUp") echo "checked";?>  value="PickUp"></td>
                    <td><img src="img/cashondelivery.gif"></td>
                    <td><p>Pick up. You have 5 days reservation period. You pay for the merchandise upon pick-up<p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="payment" <?php if (isset($payment) && $payment=="COD") echo "checked";?>  value="COD"></td>
                    <td><img src="img/Cash on Delivery.jpg" height="90" width="125"/></td>
                    <td><p>Pay with your Cash on Delivery (COD)<br>Choose this option if you have selected COD under shipping. Otherwise, choose other options for payment.<p></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table>
            <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Place Order"/></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>

    </div>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

and the commented part of my code does not work as well. i am having a hard time fixing this.

when i add  action="billingredirect.php" it doesnt input the query to the database. but when i remove it, it inserts the query.

if you are curious about my billingredirect.php here it is

```
<?php

header('refresh: 0;url=lorem.html');
$message = "You will now be redirected";
echo("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>");

?>
```

and when i add a redirect code in my script, it doesnt work as well

```
<script language="javascript">

    function validate(){
        var f=document.form1;
        f.command.value='update';
        f.submit();
        alert("Order submitted");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: did you try header('Location: lorem.html'); ?

Comment: yes i did, but it did not work aswell. i think that the problem is within my main code.

Comment: in what page is the html you are displaying? I removed your BD passwrod btw, remember to remove it next time :)

Comment: thanks @Salketer, Just redirecting in general. My query doesnt work if i redirect or something. I dont know what the exact problem is. but when i redirect, it does not insert the query into the database.

Comment: Please, in what page is the HTML? What is the name of the file?

Comment: lets just say homeframe.html @Salketer

Comment: Lets just say that your billingredirect.php is redirecting to lorem.html as your code states. You are never directing to the homeframe.html so never doing the insert. Plus, redirecting like that will make you loose all the $_GET and $_REQUEST values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
die('hehe');
```

Try adding that line of code inside your php tags, before the last } to stop the script. to check if it works

Comment: you could replace it with header('refresh: 0; url=YOURURL');
  exit();

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to a different page/script use:

```
header("location: location.php");
exit(); //stops the current script executing
```

Comment: i did that but it did not work. it redirected but it did not insert the query to the database.

Comment: You need to do the database insert in the lines before this code.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the super global `$_GET` which retrieves the data in the query string of the URL. Usually it appears after the ? in the address bar. What is does is get all the data from a GET request. The super global `$_POST` retrieves the data from a POST request.

Forms usually send POST requests, that would you do not get inside the `IF` statement.

To make sure of it, try using `var_dump($_GET)` or `var_dump($_POST)` this will print out all their content, that way you can verify what is wrong.

When redirecting on form submissions, the form data does not follow to the new page. The processing of the form data should be done in the script doing the redirection.

Comment: By default forms send as a GET request. You would have to specify POST as the method attribute in the form for it to send as POST. Also he mentioned that he is able to get the query to work when he removes the  header code so there isn't a problem with retrieving the form data.